# Function typing in TypedRacket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Is it possible to write something similar to C++'s

```
template <typename... T> std::string dup(int n, std::string s, T... tail) {
  std::string result;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      result += s;
  }
  if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) == 0) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return result + dup(tail...);
  }
}


std::cout << dup(1, std::string("abc"), 2, std::string("xyz"), 3, std::string("a")) << std::endl; // abcxyzxyzaaa
```

I tried to write the following function in TypedRacket

```
#lang typed/racket

(: repeat-string (-> Integer String String))
(define (repeat-string n str)
  (apply string-append (build-list n (λ (_) str))))

(: dup (All (T ...) (-> Integer String T ... T String)))
(define (dup n s . tail)
  (define result (repeat-string n s))
  (cond [(empty? tail) result]
        [else (string-append result (apply dup tail))])
  )
```

but i have typecheck error:
`Type Checker: Bad arguments to function in 'apply': Domain: Integer String T ... T Arguments:  (List T ... T) in: (apply dup tail)`

Honestly, i dont understand why arguments are `(List T ... T)` but not `(T ... T)`. Moreover, the function is correct, untyped Racket produces the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to doing this with proper type safety is to specify the type of your function using [`->*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._-%7E3e%2A%29%29) with a `#:rest-star` keyword:

```
#lang typed/racket

;; Version that avoids building an intermediate list
(: repeat-string : Integer String -> String)
(define (repeat-string n s)
  (define len (string-length s))
  (build-string (* n len) (lambda (i) (string-ref s (remainder i len)))))


(: dup (->* (Integer String) #:rest-star (Integer String) String))
(define (dup n s . rest)
  (if (null? rest)
      (repeat-string n s)
      (string-append (repeat-string n s) (apply dup rest))))

(dup 1 "abc" 2 "xyz" 3 "a") ; "abcxyzxyzaaa"
```

If your function takes a list directly, you can use [`Rec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.Rec%29%29) and [`List*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.List%2A%29%29) to create the type signature. You can also then define `dup` in terms of it:

```
(: dup* : (Rec IntStrRepeated (U Null (List* Integer String IntStrRepeated))) -> String)
(define (dup* pairs)
  (if (null? pairs)
      ""
      (string-append (repeat-string (car pairs) (cadr pairs)) (dup* (cddr pairs)))))

(: dup (->* (Integer String) #:rest-star (Integer String) String))
(define (dup n s . rest)
  (dup* (list* n s rest)))


(dup* '(1 "abc" 2 "xyz" 3 "a")) ; "abcxyzxyzaaa"
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you explain, please, why i have this error? After reading https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#(part._.Polymorphic_.Functions) it seemed to me that at the moment of calling T ... T would expand into an Integer String Integer String ...., but for some reason tail has type (List T ... T), not T ... T as I expected

Comment: The notation `(define (f x . ys) ...)` defines a function of 1 or more variables.
When called, x is bound to the first argument. The remaining arguments are put in a newly allocated list and bound to `xs`.  Thus, in `(define (dup n s . tail) ...)` the identifier `tail` will be bound to a list. See the section of `lambda` in the reference manual (not in the Typed Racket section).